# Non-linear loss combination

Tags: tensorflow, keras

My network has 2 outputs. I'm trying to have a loss on two terms that is not a linear sum of two losses:

```
def weightedBCE(y_true, y_pred):
    assert y_pred.shape[2] == 2
    y_pred_val = y_pred[:,:,0]
    stds = y_pred[:,:,1]
    bce = K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred_val)
    loss = bce * (1. + LAM*stds )
    return loss
```

The final layers of my model are defined like this (`outSall` has 3 values):

```
std = make_std_model()(outSall)
final = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(outSall)

output = concatenate([DSAfinal, std ], axis=-1)
```

But it doesn't work because Kears expects 1 loss function per output. My loss uses both outputs of the network together.

The first output is a standard classification one with Binary Cross Entropy loss, but I want it to be multiplied by `(1+ LAM* stds)` with a lambda factor multiplying `stds`. `stds` are the second output of the network.

How can I do this?

> assert y_pred.shape[2] == 2
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Update:
I had an extra index, now fixed. See below. But I get an error pasted below.

```
def weightedBCE(y_true, y_pred):
    assert y_pred.shape[1] == 2
    y_pred_val = y_pred[:,0]
    stds = y_pred[:,1]
    bce = K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred_val)
    loss = bce * (1. + LAM*stds )
    return loss
```

> ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((?,) vs (?, ?)

Update2:

Keras assumes the y_true has same shape as y_pred. Which was the problem. Changed the loss to:

```
def weightedBCE(y_true, y_pred):
    assert y_pred.shape[1] == 2
    y_pred_val = y_pred[:,0]
    stds = y_pred[:,1]
    bce = K.binary_crossentropy(y_true[:,0], y_pred_val)
    loss = bce * (1. + LAM*stds )
    return loss
```

There is still some problem with handling two outputs, see [Binary Cross Entropy not giving similar results when I have 2 outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56872262/binary-cross-entropy-not-giving-similar-results-when-i-have-2-outputs)

Comment: The assert tells us `y_pred` doesn't have a third axis, what's the actual shape?

Comment: Maybe I need to `expand_dim` before `concatenate`?

Comment: Well it would be easier to tell if we knew the shape.

Comment: output shape is `(?, 2)`, I had to have shape with 2 dims not 3.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a Keras model with two outputs, create a Keras model with a single output which is a concatenation of the two tensors (you can use `keras.layers.Concatenate` for that). Then you can compile the model with a single custom loss function, as the one you wrote above.

Comment: I already concatenated it but when I try to run this I get a shape error

Comment: What are the shapes of these two output tensors before you concatenate them? Do you intend to concat them on an existing axis or stack them on new one?

Comment: `output = concatenate([final, std ], axis=-1)` I intend them to be concatenated as if it was 2 outputs

Comment: When you concatenate two tensors of shapes (B, N) and (B, M) with axis=-1, you get as a result a tensor of shape (B, N + M), not a tensor with an additional axis. Perhaps this solves your issue?

Comment: ok, how can i make it concatenate on a third axis?
`output = concatenate([K.expand_dims(final, -1), K.expand_dims(std, -1) ], axis=1)` doesn't work

Comment: I just cheked that the shape are correct, there's no need to `expand_dim`